How does the Cube of Force interact with teleportation?
One of my 5e Adventurers League characters just came into possession of a Cube of Force so I decided to rebuild the character to take advantage of this item.
He is now a level 7 Oath of the Ancients Paladin with the Mage Slayer Feat. As the text implies, his main tactic is to get close to mage-type targets, activate the Cube to trap them within, and then kill them with primarily melee attacks.
Prior to asking my questions, here is the key text in 5e regarding the Cube of Force Effects (Dungeon Master's Guide P. 160):

Face 1: Gases, wind, and fog can't pass through the barrier.
Face 2: Nonliving matter can't pass through the barrier. Walls, floors, and ceilings can pass through at your discretion.
Face 3: Living matter can't pass through the barrier.
Face 4: Spell effects can't pass through the barrier.
Face 5: Nothing can pass through the barrier. Walls, floors, and ceilings can pass through at your discretion.
Face 6: The barrier deactivates.

Here is my question:
Is it correct to assume that even while using Face 4 or Face 5, that a creature trapped in the cube's 15 foot space with me will still be able to teleport to a space outside since they are not, technically, "passing through the barrier"?
Here is the text on Teleport (PHB P. 281):

This spell instantly transports you and up to eight willing creatures
of your choice that you can see within range, or a single object that
you can see within range, to a destination you select. If you target
an object, it must be able to fit entirely inside a 10-foot cube, and
it can’t be held or carried by an unwilling creature.
The destination you choose must be known to you, and it must be on the
same plane of existence as you. Your familiarity with the destination
determines whether you arrive there successfully. The DM rolls d100
and consults the table.


I went ahead and removed question 2, it’s an entirely distinct question and deserves to be treated in its own post.

You said "Is it correct to assume that even while using Face 4 or Face 6" . . . did you mean "Face 6"?  Face 6 deactivates the barrier.

@NobodytheHobgoblin yes you are correct, apologies for the typo

The cube does not block teleporting
Force effects in general do not block teleportation. Some spells, like forcecage, have special rules that require a successful saving throw to teleport out, but cube of force has no such language, so it works normally.
